# Generate string containing escaped interpolation

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/<%= @home %>/">welcome</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Nokogiri to grab the `href` properties of all its `a` tags and build an array of hashes. I am expecting:

```
[{
  :href => "/#{ @home }/",
  :title => "welcome"
}]
```

I tried this script:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(file))
menu = []

doc.css('a').each do |item|
  menu.push({
    :href => item[:href].gsub(/<%=(.*)%-?>/, "\#{\\1}"),
    :title => item.text
  })
end
```

The resulting string is automatically escaped; notice the extra backslash before the hash sign:

```
[{
  :href => "/\#{ @home }/",
  :title => "welcome"
}]
```

I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: "and I can't figure out why" - because you yourself insert escaped hash sign.

Comment: It's a double quoted string, without escaping it, it would interpolate in the gsub. Tried with unescaped # in a single quoted string. Same result.

Comment: @AndreiSerdeliuc, Try `puts menu[0][:href]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not the `'\'` in the string, it is added by the `inspect`: if you `puts` the string you will realize it:

```
asd = '<%= asd %>'.gsub(/<%=(.*)%-?>/, "\#{\\1}") #=> "\#{ asd }"

p asd #=> "\#{ asd }" <- this is `asd.inspect`, which is returned by `p`
"\#{ asd }" <- this is `asd.inspect`, which is printed by `p`

puts asd #=> nil <- this is `nil`, which is returned by `puts`
#{ asd } <- this is `asd.to_s`, and it is the actual string
```

Comment: Good point. It's not in the string. I'm using menu.pretty_inspect to grab the ruby code to stick in the resulting file, and pretty_inspect is escaping the output.