# JSON pretty print doesn't translate escape characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to output a json in a human format, i am trying to use pp and pretty_generate, but both doesn't seem to include escape characters:

```
    1.8.7 :024 > JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse({"a"=>1234, "b"=>56}.to_json))
 => "{\n  \"a\": 1234,\n  \"b\": 56\n}"
```

Comment: *"but both doesn't seem to include escape characters"* I'm seeing them, for instance `\n` in the above. What are you not seeing that you expect to see?

Comment: @Patrick is right; see for example [this anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774707/generate-string-containing-escaped-interpolation/21774932#21774932), the issue is the same (and, for God's sake, upgrade your Ruby, 1.8 is not supported anymore :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to `put` it out there

```
irb(main):007:0> JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse({"a"=>1234, "b"=>56}.to_json))
=> "{\n  \"a\": 1234,\n  \"b\": 56\n}"
irb(main):008:0> puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse({"a"=>1234, "b"=>56}.to_json))
{
  "a": 1234,
  "b": 56
}
=> nil
```